# xamarin forms dynamic image tapgesture recognizer control

Tags: xamarin, dynamic, xamarin.forms

How can I provide control (change) of my dynamic images created in xamarin forms by clicking?

```
Image ggImage = new Image()
ggImage.Source = otoTip.imagex
ggImage.AutomationId = "seat_" +otoTip.num
ggImage.WidthRequest = imageWidth
ggImage.HeightRequest = 50
ggImage.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
ggImage.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
ggImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

For example, I just want to change a resume source.

Comment: What I want to do is change the image that I just clicked when I click on the dynamically created image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a TapGestureRecognizer and then add it to your image...

```
Image ggImage = new Image();
ggImage.Source = otoTip.imagex
ggImage.AutomationId = "seat_" +otoTip.num
ggImage.WidthRequest = imageWidth        
ggImage.HeightRequest = 50;
ggImage.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
ggImage.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

// your TapGestureRecognizer implementation, this is just a sample...
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => { ggImage.Source = yourNewSource };
ggImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

In order to change every unique image of your dynamically created images you could extend your `OtoTip` class and

```
public class OtoTip : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }
    public int near { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }

    public int yy { get; set; }
    public int xx { get; set; }


    // xx
    private string _imagex;
    public string imagex
    {
        get { return _imagex; }
        set
        {
            _imagex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(imagex));
        }
    }

    private string _imageActivex;
    public string imageActivex
    {
        get { return _imageActivex; }
        set
        {
            _imageActivex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(imageActivex));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You have to extend your `getVoyagesData()` now, to also set the `imageActivex` like your standard image.

Now you have to adjust the TapGestureRecognizer to use the new property

```
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => 
{ 
    if(ggImage.Source = otoTip.imagex) {
        ggImage.Source = otoTip.imageActivex;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        ggImage.Source = otoTip.imagex;
    }
};
```

Does this help?

Comment: thank you but There is more than one picture from a picture so there is a bus plan available. I want to change the source of the seat number 4, for example. how can i provide it? [link](http://prntscr.com/jixulw)

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying... maybe a little bit more code of your project or even an image of what you want to achieve could be helpful? What do you mean by `one picture from a picture`. Every image has its own TapGestureRecognizer so you just have to adjust the tapped event.

Comment: I use translation , sorry. what I want to do is you can see the picture on the link above. Is not there a bus seating plan in my picture? For example, when I click image 4, I want to change the image of the empty seat image = (male or female)

Comment: [image](http://prntscr.com/jixz7u)  my dynamic image codes. I thought it would change with automationid but this is not possible

Comment: sorry, just overlooked the link! :( AutomationId is there to find the element for the automation framework (e.g. for testing purposes). Let me just try something out, I will update my answer...

Comment: my seat plan image = [http://prntscr.com/jixulw ](http://prntscr.com/jixulw )  How can I control (change) only one image in my images that I create dynamically? it has been a long time and I still can not get the result thank you for the help

Comment: Could you provide the code of your `OtoTip` class? Maybe it could be enough to add another property there which holds the image to which it should change after clicking on it

Comment: ototip class : [https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2bRcMgkfCM/](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2bRcMgkfCM/)  bus.cs class = [https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/87jXvF8bzk/](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/87jXvF8bzk/) bus.xml = [https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/74vqXxZgq2/](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/74vqXxZgq2/)

Comment: Glad that I could help, please mark the answer as the accepted if it helped you ;) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers